# How to bind GraphicsLayer to RadGridView?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, wpf

I'd like to bind an [Esri WPF GraphicsLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.GraphicsLayer.html) to Telerik's [RadGridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx) control.

Does anyone have any examples showing how to do this?

Examples showing how to do it with Silverlight would also be useful.

Comment: have you see Find Task with WPF ? Change DataGrid with RadGridView.